# syntax to override gsettings bytestring

Tags: gsettings

I am trying to define a gsetting default for nemo in an override file.
The key (`org.nemo.preferences bulk-rename-tool`) is of `type="ay"`, which means it's a bytestring as explained on [developer.gnome.org](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/gvariant-text.html)

After setting it to gprename in nemo's preferences dialog the returned value for `gsettings get org.nemo.preferences bulk-rename-tool` is `b’gprename’` and
in the running environment I can successfully set the value with
`gsettings set org.nemo.preferences bulk-rename-tool "b’gprename’"`
But I fail at finding the correct syntax to include in an override file.

I've tried square brackets, double/single quotes, including the nul terminator as mentioned on developer.gnome.org in all kinds of combinations and variations - without success.

For example

```
[org.nemo.preferences]
bulk-rename-tool="b’gprename’"
```

leads to

```
# glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/

error parsing key 'bulk-rename-tool' in schema 'org.nemo.preferences' as
specified in override file '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/99_custom-cinnamon.gschema.override':
0-13:can not parse as value of type 'ay'.Ignoring override for this key.
```

Or

```
bulk-rename-tool=[b’gprename’]
```

gives

```
error parsing key 'bulk-rename-tool' in schema 'org.nemo.preferences' as
specified in override file '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/99_custom-cinnamon.gschema.override':
1:expected value.Ignoring override for this key.
```

Since the default in the schema lists just empty brackets `[]`, I have also tried stuff like

```
bulk-rename-tool=[b’gprename'\0]
```

which gives me

```
1.14:unterminated string constant.
```

So maybe this is the closest to working, just the nul terminator is apparently wrong syntax...

Answer (score 1):

```
[org.nemo.preferences]
bulk-rename-tool=b'thunar --bulk-rename'
```

Don't use quotes in the config override "...". You would only use them if you set the value via cli, i.e.

```
$ dconf write /org/nemo/preferences/bulk-rename-tool "b'thunar --bulk-rename'"
```

The compile line you have posted is correct and all should work.

```
$ glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```